# What does AdditionalDependencies in an Unreal .uproject file mean?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-development-kit, unreal-engine5

In an Unreal Engine `.uproject` file there is a `Modules` section which lists the project-specific modules with a source code folder under the `Source` folder.

Each such module definition has an `AdditionalDependencies` field with a list of strings.

What is the meaning of this `AdditionalDependencies` field?  Is it a list of modules or plugins?

If modules, what does it mean for a module A to have a dependency on module B?  That is, what effect does this listing have:

```
"Modules":[
{
  "Name":"A",
  ...
  "AdditionalDependencies":[
    "B"
  ]
},
...
]
```

Each module has an associated build file `.Build.cs`, and in it is contained `PublicDependencyModuleNames` and `PrivateDependencyModuleNames` lists.

Is the kind of module dependency declared by `.uproject/AdditionalDependencies` different from the kind of module dependency declared by `.Build.cs/DependencyModuleNames` ?  If so, how?

(Crossposted https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/what-does-the-additionaldependencies-field-mean-in-uproject-modules-section/589091?u=zos and https://www.reddit.com/r/unrealengine/comments/vjg6q9/what_does_additionaldependencies_in_an_unreal/)

Answer (score 1):

I found this note about the field at https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/unreal-engine-modules/:

> AdditionalDependencies (array): Specifies additional dependencies needed by the module. **You should specify this in your Build.cs files instead.**

So what I suspect is that the `AdditionalDependencies` field is some kind of evolutionary left over, and that the dependencies declared in the `.Build.cs` file are intended to completely replace it.

I have entirely removed the `AdditionalDependencies` fields from my `.uproject` file, and thus far have not observed any ill-effects.

I'd still be curious to know the story behind it if anyone knows.